# Sending Update Model to MongoDB Model through postman

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, mongodb-.net-driver

```
public class BaseEntity
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    }

public class Order : BaseEntity
    {
        public string OrderId { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Payment Payment { get; set; }
        public OrderStatus OrderStatus { get; set; }
        public ShippingAddress ShippingAddress { get; set; }
        public BillingAddress BillingAddress { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Double)]
        public decimal Discount { get; set; }
        //public BsonDateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    }

// PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Put(string id, [FromBody]Order Order)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            await OrderContext.Put<Order>(x => x.OrderId == id, Order);
            return Ok(Order);
        }
```

[image]

This is my request body.But I am getting the `Order` model as null.I am not sure why .

I have a model Order which inherits from **`BaseEntity`** . I am trying to pass a model for PUT request from postman . But I am receiving the **`Order`** model as null .

However the interesting thing is if I remove `id` property from the request body I am getting all the model populated as the request body except the `id` field from the base entity. I receive the id property as `00000000000000` in that second case .

Comment: @MarcusH The issue is not the Id in the request param . I am talking about the Order model property Id. I think I would reframe the question a bit

Comment: I think the problem lays in the json hierarchies deserialization. Check this blog out http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.se/2012/02/json-deserialization-with-jsonnet-class.html